# Are there tools for compiling CommonJS modules into a single .js file?

Tags: javascript

Are there any tools that can compile modules written with CommonJS/Node-like modules (`require`, `exports`, etc.) into a single .js file to be served to a browser?

Comment: Do you need the modules to be written in COmmonJS style or are you OL with other alternatives too?

Comment: @missingno, I think I'd prefer CommonJS style, but I'm open to alternatives. (I'm not interested in AMD/RequireJS style though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for *Browserify*:

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

> "Make node-style require() work in the browser with a server-side build
>   step, as if by magic!"

Answer (score 1):

Another quite similar utility named CommonJS Compiler and Grunt task respectively you can find at https://github.com/dsheiko/cjsc

It uses Esprima syntaxTree while parsing require() calls in the modules. It enclosures each module in a unique scope and does the caching in the very way nodejs does.  It works fine with UMD (universal module definition) modules. What I like most, it adds during compiling very little of code - small require function body plus define-call wrapper per module.

Comment: CommonJS Compiler now supports source maps, therefore all the breakpoints and console messages mapped to the original sources

Answer (score 0):

If you want something you can use directly from PHP, try [cjsDelivery](https://github.com/mattcg/cjsDelivery).